# Why is my code returning an "ascii codec" error when I'm trying to use utf-8?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I'm new to Python, and am only starting to use it as part of a CTF challenge (I'm a cybersecurity student). I was given a mostly pre-built "decoder" script, and the assignment was to complete it. So, I have my word list imported into the script as a list variable, I have a while loop running through each word, it's all great...except as soon as a non-ASCII character comes up in the word list (in this case it's the word "Français") I get this error thrown at me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dict.py", line 32, in <module>
    cipher = AES.new(secret + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(codecs.encode(secret, 'utf-8' )) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING, AES.MODE_ECB)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Which would make sense if the code didn't specify utf-8 encoding, plus when I `echo $LANG` in the terminal I get `en_GB.UTF-8`...not ascii!

For reference, here's the original code as I received it:

```
# pip install pycryptodome
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

BLOCK_SIZE = 32

PADDING = '{'

# Encrypted text to decrypt
encrypted = "9l21XiUohS1j9kUx02KJNAkjw51pupGgiMlCkuVNEMo="

def decode_aes(c, e):
    return c.decrypt(base64.b64decode(e)).decode('latin-1').rstrip(PADDING)

secret = "password"

if secret[-1:] == "\n":
    print("Error, new line character at the end of the string. This will not match!")
elif len(secret.encode('utf-8')) >= 32:
    print("Error, string too long. Must be less than 32 bytes.")
else:
    # create a cipher object using the secret
    cipher = AES.new(secret + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(secret.encode('utf-8')) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING, AES.MODE_ECB)

    # decode the encoded string
    decoded = decode_aes(cipher, encrypted)

    if decoded.startswith('FLAG:'):
        print("\n")
        print("Success: "+secret+"\n")
        print(decoded+"\n")
    else:
        print('Wrong password')
```

and here it is after I've modified it (unchanged portion omitted):

```
with open('words.txt', 'r') as f:
    words = f.readlines()

i = 0

while i < len(words):

    secret = words[i][0:-1]
    print(secret)

    if secret[-1:] == "\n":
        print("Error, new line character at the end of the string. This will not match!")
    elif len(secret.encode('utf-8')) >= 32:
        print("Error, string too long. Must be less than 32 bytes.")
    else:
        # create a cipher object using the secret
        cipher = AES.new(secret + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(secret.encode('utf-8')) % BLOCK_SIZE) * PADDING, AES.MODE_ECB)

        # decode the encoded string
        decoded = decode_aes(cipher, encrypted)

        if decoded.startswith('FLAG:'):
            print("\n")
            print("Success: "+secret+"\n")
            print(decoded+"\n")
            break
        else:
            print('Wrong password')
            print(i)
            i += 1
```

This works up until "Français."

I'm running it in Python 2.7. I've tried running it in python3, but then the import of Crypto.Cipher doesn't work `(ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Crypto')`, and I really don't know enough about Python to be able to fix that. I have also tried installing the codecs module and replacing `secret.encode('utf-8')` with `codecs.encode(secret,'utf-8')` but I get the same error.

I don't need anyone to solve the rest of this assignment for me. If there are other reasons my code won't work, don't tell me, I'll figure it out. But this encoding thing really doesn't seem like it's meant to be part of the challenge, and I'm stumped as to what to do next. Why is it using ASCII as its default encoding despite arguments to the contrary, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Please post the full error message including traceback, so it's clear where it originates.

Comment: done! thanks for telling me

Comment: Python 2 does a lot of implicit encoding and decoding if you're mixing up bytes and strings incorrectly. Likely the problem stems from something like that. Having said that, Python 2 is ancient and dead. You should not be writing any new code in Python 2, nor should you have to learn Python 2 and its pitfalls. Use Python 3 and solve your module error there, then go from there.

Comment: `secret` is likely already encoded.  Its type would be`str` in Python 2, equivalent to `bytes` in Python 3.  In Python 2 an implicit `.decode('ascii')` would be used to convert `secret` to a `unicode` type (and hence the error) so `secret.encode('utf-8')` would then be possible.  The `print` statements are Python 3-style, so you probably should be using Python 3, and just need to install the `pycryptodome` using `pip`.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I'd say you're right, that `secret.encode()` is the culprit with an implicit `decode` being thrown in by Python 2.  Except that there's another `secret.encode()` a couple of lines before the error, that *didn't* trigger an error.

Comment: @MarkRansom it wouldn’t be the first time we don’t have a reproducible example.

Comment: Don't use Python 2

Comment: @MarkRansom actually, that's my bad, that encode above also triggers an error. I forgot I commented the length check lines out to see if that would fix the problem when I posted the error message. Thanks for the advice everybody, I'll use Python 3 instead!

Comment: If you wanted to quickly try something, you could just use `secret` as-is without calling `encode` on it.  Should eliminate your error at least.